# what's problem with swiftui sheet under macos

Tags: macos, swiftui

my code works under the ios,but under macos , the sheet will repeat "show close" loop auto. when I click the button edit ,the sheet shows on the top of the window,then I click the button close on the sheet,the sheet disappeared,but appear again immediately,and close auto,apear auto ,a loop
main view code:

```
struct NewWordsView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: WordFrequency.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \WordFrequency.bookName, ascending: true)])
    var words:FetchedResults<WordFrequency>
    @State var showDetail:Bool = false
    @State var wordIndex:Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(self.words.indices, id:\.self){ idx in
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {self.deleteWords(idx:idx)}){
                        Text("X")
                    }
                    Button(action:{
                        self.showDetail.toggle()
                        self.wordIndex = idx

                    }){
                        Text("edit")
                    }
                    Text(self.words[idx].word!)
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetail){
                EditWordView( showDetail: self.$showDetail,word: self.words[self.wordIndex])
            }


        }
    }
```

subview code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditWordView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @Binding var showDetail:Bool
    let  word:WordFrequency
    @State var chinese:String = ""
    var body: some View {


            VStack{
                Button(action:{
                    self.showDetail.toggle()

                }){
                    Text("close")

                }
                Text("\(word.word ?? "")")
                    .font(.title)

                TextField("中文解释", text: self.$chinese)
                .font(.title)

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have similar problem as was reported and solved in [How do I keep multiple button actions separate in SwiftUI ForEach content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960077/how-do-i-keep-multiple-button-actions-separate-in-swiftui-foreach-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code should after List view, not ForEach.

```
 .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetail){
                EditWordView( showDetail: self.$showDetail,word: self.words[self.wordIndex])
            }
```