# SwiftUI list rown and buttons in same section in edit mode do not allow actions

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-environment

SwiftUI list rown and buttons in same section in edit mode do not allow actions

**Goal** Would like to have clickable buttons in list and section, movable and deletable rows in list

code:

```swift
Section(header: Text("HEADER")) {
  List {
    ForEach(dataList) { data in
      Button {
        // action will not be called
        print("action will not be called")
      } label: {
        Text("Button in list")
      } // Button
    } // ForEach
      .onMove(perform: onMove)
  } // List

  Button {
    // action will not be called
    print("action will not be called")
  } label: {
    Text("Button in section")
  }

} // Section
// .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964567/12299030? Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813896/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi unfortunately, the onTapGesture is only triggered if I tap the button text :(